# How to create bargraph along with dynamic values and static values in android using achartengine

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I need to plot bar graph. In bar graph one bar, will be updated dynamically and other bars are static. Every time the graph needs to be updated dynamically with the values and displayed along with static values. Also I need to create a source file for updating dynamic values. Can any one help me with this.

Comment: I am not able to add the image as I need 10 reputations to do so. I have edited my question

Answer (score 2):

[This video](http://youtu.be/E9fozQ5NlSo) should be able to help. It's as easy as updating your data and then calling repaint() on the chart.

In your case, the coca-cola data will be updated, but the rest will not. Without more information on what you are trying to do/where the data is coming from it is hard to help.

Is a user typing in the data or are you retrieving it from a web service?

Comment: I have seen that video, it shows only for dynamic values. I need combination of dynamic and static values in a graph. For data to be received for dynamic values I need it to be read from a file as user can change the values as and when needed.

Comment: Right, but you could have static datasets saved somewhere and simply just update the dynamic one. And how much data are we talking about here? You could use SQLite to store persistent data for your app, or you could do something as simple as write to a parse-able text file. Or if you need more structure look into something like JSON.

Comment: I need to read the data from a file. So, probably I will look into how to read contents from the file.

Comment: And how you read contents from a file depends on what type of file you are using.

Comment: I will be using text file

Comment: I'm just trying to wrap my head around how you are updating the dynamic data. From what I understand, the user would update the numbers which would be saved into the text file. Then the graph pulls those values from the text file whenever they are updated?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same what you are saying.

Comment: I know they are static, but where do the other values come from?

Comment: What do you mean by where other values come from? Is it you are mentioning about static then those values will be stored in an array and taken to plot. If it is dynamic then these values are taken from text file and plotted. Every time user enters data in the text file then every time the image has to be refreshed with new values.